# efficient breadth first search using sql joins

Tags: sql, postgresql, binary-search-tree, breadth-first-search, ecto

I'm dealing with a binary tree.

So I have a database table in my database where each node is a parent to up to 2 other nodes. I have a plan to efficiently find the top most node (under a given node) that is a parent to less than 2 other nodes. I'm looking for the top most open position to place a new node in other words. So I have this implemented as a breadth-first search. But the way I'm calling the database for each and every node is inefficient. I'm basically going down the tree, producing a running list of nodes on each level and checking each one if it is a parent to two other nodes.

Here's a diagram:
[image]

And here's the code if you'd like to see it:

```
  # breadth-first search
  def build_and_return_parent_id(breadth_list) do
        [ {node_id} | tail ] = breadth_list

        child_list = fetch_children_id(node_id)

        bc_list = tail ++ child_list

        case length(child_list) do
          x when x > 2 ->


            # recursion
            build_and_return_parent_id(bc_list)

          2 ->

            # recursion
            build_and_return_parent_id(bc_list)

          _ -> node_id
        end
  end

  def fetch_children_id(id) do
    Repo.all( from n in Node,
              where: n.parent_id == ^id,
              order_by: [asc: n.inserted_at],
              select: {n.id})
  end
end
```

So instead of doing that so inefficiently - one db call per node - I was thinking, how about I produce a list of all the nodes that have less than two parents, then travel down the tree, for each level use one db call to get a list of all the nodes on that level, then simply compare the two lists. if there are matching IDs in both the lists I've found a node that has an available spot under it.

Here's a diagram:

[image]

The problem is I know almost nothing about sql queries. my guess is that this can be done with some kind of self join on the table.

```
node_id   |  parent_id
----------------------
1         |  nil
2         |  1
3         |  1
4         |  2
5         |  2
6         |  3
7         |  4
8         |  5
9         |  6
10        |  3
```

So anyway I'm sure if this method works someone has done it before but I can't seem to find any information on the kinds of sql queries that would be used to generate the open list or the level list.

Now I suppose the 2nd query is pretty simple. since we have an open list we can just use a where-in-[list] clause. Byt the first one I think is the one I'm struggling with.

If you have anything you can point me to or help you can offer I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Is this ecto? Which database engine? Postgresql? Those are more important things to tag, than `join`, `self-join`.

Comment: @trincot It is ecto and yes, it is postgresql

Comment: SQL is a declarativelanguage, you have no real influence over the method ussed or the order of operations. But *probably* a recursive query will build up the query result in the layered way that you want. Generating a `level`  expression, ordering on it,  and stopping the query once the first tuple with no children is found seems doable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add columns `depth` and `child_count` and create an index:

```
create index nodes_depth_1child_idx on nodes(depth) where child_count=1;
```

Then searching should be basically instant with:

```
select node_id from nodes where child_count=1 order by depth limit 1;
```

You should also create triggers that would maintain these values. This would slow down insert operations slightly, as the insert would have to read the parent node `depth` and update the parent node `child_count`.